# PHP + MySQL - how to check if logged in before proceeding to checkout

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing a school project where I have to create a website. I'm not very good at php and find it very confusing.  What I need to accomplish is to make it so that when a customer clicks a "buy now" button and enters their email address, the page will 1. write their order to a database ONLY AFTER checking if they are logged in already. If the customer is NOT LOGGED IN, they will be redirected to the log in page.

```
<?php
    //  Start a PHP session
    session_start();

    // Check to see if user is already logged in
    if(isset($_SESSION["sname"]))
    {
        header('Location: custwelcome.php');
        exit;
    }

?>
```

As I assume, this should make sure that the session variable stored from the customer's log in exist.

Would I place this body of code before the php code that writes a customer's order to the database? Or would I place it on the "product's" detailed page. (For the assignment, it doesn't matter if the web page checks before or after the clicking of the "buy now" button. it just has to check).

If this doesn't provide enough detail, here is my product page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- XXXX 
project
athletic1.htm -->

<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Meta tag -->
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex.nofollow" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!-- Link tag for CSS -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheet/project.css" />

    <!-- Javascript tags -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/projectmessages.js"></script>


    <!-- Web Page Title -->
    <title>Shoe Source Unlimited - Athletic Shoe Sale</title>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header">

                <img src="../images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />

    <p class="sh1">Shoe Source Unlimited</p>
    <p class="sh2">Your source for lightning sales of this season's hot shoes!    </p>

        <p class="sh3">XXXXX </p>
  </div>

    <div id="navbar">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="../homepage.htm">Home</a>                          
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Men's</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="../sneakers.htm">Sneakers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../loafers.htm">Loafers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../athletic.htm">Athletic</a></li>
                    </ul>                       
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Women's</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="../boots.htm">Boots</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../heels.htm">Heels</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../sandals.htm">Sandals</a></li>       
                    </ul>               
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="../about.htm">About Us</a>         

            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="../signup.htm">Sign Up</a>

            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="../login.php">Log In</a>

            </li>

        </ul>   
    </div>




  <div id="external">

    <p>

            <a href="https://twitter.com/XXXXX" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">
                <img src="../images/twitter.jpg" alt="twitter" />
            </a>
     </p>
            <p>Follow us on Twitter!</p>
        <br/>


    <p>

            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ShoeSourceUnlimited" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">
                <img src="../images/facebook.png" alt="facebook" />
            </a>
    </p>
            <p>Like us on Facebook!</p>
              <br/>


        <a href="../em/projectem.htm">
        <img src="../images/email.jpg" alt="pinkemail"  />
        </a>
    </p>    
            <p> Send us an email!</p>   
    </div>  




<form id="joinform" action="../purchaseconfirm.php" method="post">
    <div id="about">

        <p class="abouttitle">Grey Athletic Shoe with Orange Enhancements</p>
        <p class="abouttitle"><img src="../images/shoes/athletic1.jpg" alt="athletic1" /></p>
        <p class="description">This low-top athletic shoe is designed for comfort during long-use.
    The bright orange color is just bright enough to show some flash without going over the top!</p>

    <p class="price">Price: $22.00 - tax included </p><br/><br/>    

        <!--Email -->
                <p class="size">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required
                title="Email: 6-59 characters, lowercase, valid email     only!"
                pattern="[a-z0-9.-_]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}"
                maxlength="60"
                onfocus="emailmsg()" />
                </p>

        <!-- Pick a size -->

                <select name="size" id="size" required title="Select a size" >
                <option value="">Select a size...</option>
                <option value="athletic1size10">Grey and Orange Mens 10</option>
                <option value="athletic1size10.5">Grey and Orange Mens 10.5</option>
                </select>   


        <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" 
                value=" Buy Now! "/>
            <br/><br/>
        </p>        
    </div>

</form>





    <div id="footer">

        <p>

            &copy;2014, XXXXX

        </p>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

And here is my "confirmation page" for all purchases:

```
<!--  
project
purchaseconfirm.php -->

<!-- this will write to DB -->



<?php
// Connect to LOCAL or SERVER MySQL Database. Just change between local and server
    include('connect/local-connect.php');

// initialize and populate PHP variables from user-entered data

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $size = $_POST['size'];



//Build a MySQL statement to populate the database table
    $query =
    "INSERT INTO shopping (email, size)
    VALUES ('$email', '$size')";

// Run the query we just built
     $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die('Unable to write to database');

// Close the database connection
    mysqli_close($dbc);

?>






<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Meta tag -->
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex.nofollow" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!-- Link tag for CSS -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/project.css" />

    <!-- Javascript tags -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/projectmessages.js"></script>


    <!-- Web Page Title -->
    <title>Shoe Source Unlimited - Purchase Confirmation</title>

  </head>

   <body>
     <div id="header">

                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />

        <p class="sh1">Shoe Source Unlimited</p>
        <p class="sh2">Your source for lightning sales of this season's hot shoes!</p>

        <p class="sh3">XXXXX</p>
  </div>

    <div id="navbar">
         <ul id="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="homepage.htm">Home</a>                         
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Men's</a>
                    <ul>
                         <li><a href="sneakers.htm">Sneakers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="loafers.htm">Loafers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="athletic.htm">Athletic</a></li>
                    </ul>                       
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Women's</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="boots.htm">Boots</a></li>
                        <li><a href="heels.htm">Heels</a></li>
                        <li><a href="sandals.htm">Sandals</a></li>      
                     </ul>              
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="about.htm">About Us</a>            

            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="signup.htm">Sign Up</a>

            </li>

            <li> 
                <a href="login/login.php">Log In</a>

            </li>

        </ul>   
    </div>


  <div id="external">

    <p>

            <a href="https://twitter.com/XXXXX" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">
                <img src="images/twitter.jpg" alt="twitter" />
            </a>
    </p>
            <p>Follow us on Twitter!</p>
        <br/>


    <p>

            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ShoeSourceUnlimited" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">
                <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="facebook" />
            </a>
    </p>
            <p>Like us on Facebook!</p>
        <br/>


        <a href="email/projectem.htm">
         <img src="images/email.jpg" alt="pinkemail"    />
        </a>

            <p> Send us an email! </p>  
    </div>      

    <div id="main">
    <p>Purchase Confirmed!</p>

    </div>

    <div id="about">
       <p class="bold">


        </p>

        <p> Your payment has been approved and your purchase shall be shipped to     you shortly </p>
        <br/>
        <p> Feel free to contact us with any further questions.</p>
        <br/>
<form id="joinform" action="homepage.htm" method="get">
        <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" 
                value=" Home Page "/>

    </div>







    <div id="footer">

        <p>

            &copy;2014, XXXXX

        </p>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

I have tried applying the first code to each of these documents, but without luck -- i could still "purchase" without being logged in.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: whenever you feel that a user must be logged in before he can do some private jobs then you must first check whether the user has already been logged in

Comment: would the php code i posted in the first "code box" be enough? because it is checking for the session variables, correct?

Answer (score 0):

you can do like

```
if (!isset($_SESSION))
  {
    session_start();
  }

// Check to see if user is already logged in
    if(isset($_SESSION["sname"]))
    {
        header('Location: custwelcome.php');
    }
```